# Compress a tar file without extracting the content

Tags: files, tar, compression

Is it possible to compress a tar file such that I don't end up with an archive file in an other archive file but just an archive file containing my content fx. a tar.gz file? 
I don't want to extract the content of the tar file, since this is a very large file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compressing a tar file with `gzip`, `bzip2` or `xz` after it is created without compression, is the same tarring + compressing the original data with `tar` + the `z`, `j`, resp. `J` option.